# How to create an automatic alarm clock in eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse

I am creating an alarm app 
and want to know how to let people set their own time and choice of sound 
I want them to type in the time they want then to select a choice of sounds to choose from.
Please Help!
Thanks

Comment: what have you got so far, and where are you stuck?

Comment: im new to programming. so far i have imported the sounds into my raw folder and have created a backround and a splash screen. Can someone tell me what to do next?

Comment: it's gunna be a looong discussion if we have to explain each step. your best bet is to search for an alarm clock tutorial online. I'm sure there are many.

Answer (score 8):

Take a look at [this tutorial](http://blog.nelsondev.net/?p=124). Go through it, try to figure it out, spend a lot of time on it. You learn best when you push yourself to your limit. Then when you are really stumped, come here and ask a ***specific*** question about how to do something. Then when someone gives a good response, accept their answer by clicking the check mark next to the answer. Good luck and welcome to Android!

Comment: I owe you big time my friend!

Comment: can you tell me how i can logout of stack overflow?

Comment: So will you accept it again? Log out by hovering over your name on the top of the screen and then hit Logout.